# Proof of a fact in pre-abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

It seems to me that my teacher in a lecture used that, in an abelian category, every monomorphism is the kernel of its cokernel. In order to prove this, I would prove that in a pre-abelian category, if a monomorphism $f:A\to B$ is the kernel of some morphism, then $f$ is the kernel of its cokernel. So I supposed to have a morphism $x:X\to B$ such that $\text{Coker} f \circ g =0$, but then I don't know how to continue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the given definition of pre-abelian?

Comment: A pre-additive category with all finite limits and colimits

Comment: and pre-additive means?

Comment: You can definitely prove that every kernel (which is automatic a monomorphism) is the kernel of its cokernel in a pre-abelian category. However, I'm not convinced that every monomorphism is automatically a kernel in a pre-abelian category.

Comment: I didn't say I want to prove that every monomorphism is a kernel in a pre-abelian category, I literally asked how to prove that a kernel is the kernel of its cokernel (since you confirmed it's possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll prove that a kernel is the kernel of its cokernel.

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be the kernel of a map $g\colon Y\to Z$. Let $c\colon Y\to C$ be the cokernel of $f$ (which exists in a pre-abelian category). We need to show that $f$ satisfies the universal property of the kernel of $c$.

1. The composition $c\circ f=0$ as $c$ is the cokernel of $f$.
2. Let $t\colon T\to Y$ be a map such that $c\circ t=0$. As $g\circ f=0$ and $c$ is the cokernel of $f$, there exists a unique map $u\colon C\to Z$ such that $u\circ c=g$. Now, $g\circ t=u\circ (c\circ t)=0$. As $f$ is the kernel of $g$, there now exists a unique map $s\colon T\to X$ such that $t=f\circ s$. This completes the proof.

Comment: +1 for pure definition[-al[?]] proof

Comment: Thank you, very clear. The map $u$ actually is from $C$ to $Z$ right?

Comment: You are right Dorian, I messed up the target of that map.